# Azuma's inequality: Expected sum of differences

Tags: probability, inequality, martingales, sums-of-squares

I am looking for an extension of Azuma's inequality which involves the *expected* sum of squared differences. In particular, recall that Azuma's inequality states
\begin{align*}
\Pr[X_n-X_0 \geq a] \leq \exp\big(\frac{-a^2}{\sum_{k=1}^n c_k^2}\big)
\end{align*}
I am looking for a similar version which involves $\mathbb{E} \sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2$, while we can still enjoy the extra assumption of $0\leq c_i\leq 1$ if it is needed.
Any comments/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: For simplicity, we also can assume that, conditioned on $X_{k-1}$, $X_k−X_{k−1}$ can only take values from a set of size 2, say {−0.1,0.1}

Answer (score 2):

In some manner or other, you have to account for the case when $X_k - X_{k-1}$ is heavy tailed.  Just consider the case $n=1$, and you can create counterexamples easily.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In fact, in my application, $X_k-X_{k-1}$ has a very simple distribution, it can only take values from a set of size $2$, say $\{-0.1,0.1\}$.

Comment: Try something like $X_k-X_{k-1} = 1$ with probability $\lambda \approx \frac1n$, and the other value something very small.  If the $X_k-X_{k-1}$ are independent, then $X_n-X_0$ is well approximated by a Poisson R.V. with parameter $n\lambda$.  Could you construct a counterexample from this?

Comment: Or $X_k-X_{k-1}=1$ with probability $\lambda \approx \frac\mu n$, where $\mu$ is large, but much smaller than $n$, so $X_n-X_0$ is well approximated by Poisson with parameter $\mu$.

Comment: Yeah, I see the point. Thanks! I'll think a bit more about it to see if other assumptions can possibly help to get such a bound.

Comment: OK, but I am doing back of an envelope calculations, and I wasn't finding a counterexample.  So I don't know if the check mark is fully deserved.  Also, look at Theorem 3.1 in http://www.math.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/disttail.html - if your desired result isn't true, this might provide a reasonable replacement.

Comment: yeah, your counter example shows that it's not possible to get a bound with $-a^2$ in the numerator of the exponent, but it still does not rule out the existence of weaker bounds, e.g. with $-a\ln a$ in the exponent (which is good enough for my application). I'll remove the check mark, but thanks a lot for your example :)

Comment: $a \ln a$ is the kind of thing the result in the paper http://www.math.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/disttail.html gives.  Are you dealing with sums of independent random variables?

Comment: No actually, they can be dependent: we know that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ form a martingale, and that for all $k$, conditioned on $X_1,\ldots,X_k$, the random variable $X_{k+1}$ can only take two values. That's why I can't see how to use [your paper](http://math.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/disttail.html).
Is it still possible? Thanks!

Comment: Have you come across the concept of tangent sequences to martingales?  They provide a way of producing martingale inequalities from inequalities for independent random variables.  I think to push it to tail probabilities is a little beyond their scope.  But maybe something slightly weaker could be proven.  I have a couple of papers on tangent sequences http://www.math.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/tangent.html http://www.math.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/concrete.html - even if the papers are not too helpful, they contain many references.  If you like, you can email me.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I will look at the papers/references and will contact you if I got stuck. Thanks for your help!